# Chart.js can't push dataset to charts made dynamically

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am currently making a web application where users can add their own chart panels, and can then drag certain database tables into said panel to make it show in the chart. My problem is that I can't push datasets into the dynamically created charts, because the variable which holds the chart are not written directly in the document, so the function I made to push those datasets can't push to the variables like it would normally.

Here's the function to make new panels and charts:

```
function addnewchart(x) {
        eval("ctx" + x + "= document.getElementById('linechart" + x + "').getContext('2d');");  
        eval("var lineChart" + x + " = new Chart(ctx" + x + ", {type: 'line',data: {labels: '',datasets: ''},options: {legend: {display: false},scales: {xAxes: [{gridLines: {display: false},scaleLabel: {display: true,labelString: ''}}],yAxes: [{ticks: {beginAtZero: true},scaleLabel: {display: true,labelString: ''}}]}}});");
    };
```

And this is the function to push datasets to those charts:

```
function addData(chart, Datalabel, Tabledata) {
        datasintable.push(Tabledata + "S");
        var curColor = randomColor();

        var newDataset =
        {
            label: Datalabel,
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: curColor,
            borderColor: curColor,
            data: Tabledata
        }

        console.log(chart,Datalabel,Tabledata, newDataset);

        chart.data.labels.push(['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5']);
        chart.data.datasets.push(newDataset);
        chart.update();
    }
```

How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the way to fix this was instead of using the variable chart in addData(), use `window[chartname + index]` when manipulating dynamically created charts. I found this out by trying to point to the chart by using both eval() and window[]. Eval didn't work at all, but Window did the trick.

Example:

```
var number = 1;
window['linechart' + number];
```

This will call chart linechart1.